# DOCTYPE affects rendering of line-height

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, doctype

This one's a head scratcher.

I've created a commented jsFiddle to demonstrate the phenomenon I recently encountered while using Twitter's Bootstrap framework to create some dropdown buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/WKvPv/

Basically, when using an HTML5, HTML 4 Strict or XHTML Strict DOCTYPE, the button renders as designed. However, when using an HTML4 or XHTML **Transitional** DOCTYPE, the caret button renders with a shorter height. Here's the relevant CSS from Bootstrap for the `<span class="caret">` (i've removed styles that don't matter, like colors and gradients):

```
.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 4px solid #000000;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}

.btn .caret {
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 4px 10px 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  line-height: 18px;
  *line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Why does the DOCTYPE affect the height of the button? If `line-height` is set to 18px, why would the height be less than 18px?

*PS - Yes, I'm aware that Bootstrap requires HTML5, but I'd imagine that's with respect to the HTML5 features utilized, not how the DOCTYPE renders CSS styles*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While writing this question and the related jsFiddle demo, I wound up doing some more digging and found out what's happening. Rather than scrap the question, I figured I may as well post it with this answer.

What I've gathered from inspecting the elements in Chrome after switching DOCTYPES is this:

- `.btn` has no height specified, only `line-height: 18px` and `padding: 4px 10px`
- in HTML5, the final height of the caret-only button is 18px, same as the defined `line-height`
- in a Transitional DOCTYPE, the height of the caret-only button is 11px, same as the `outerHeight()` of the `caret` (`border-top` + `margin-top`), but less than the `line-height` of the button.

So, I can only assume that Strict (and HTML5) DOCTYPEs enforce `line-height` as some kind of `min-height`; even if there is no text in the element, it applies `line-height` ... whereas Transitional DOCTYPES do not.

When I add some text to the caret-only button (`&nbsp;` for example), then `line-height` kicks in on Transitional DOCTYPEs and the button renders at the full height.

Comment: Transitional DOCTYPEs trigger what's called almost standards mode, which is basically standards mode with a few quirks. Since this has to do with the box model, you *may* be running into one of those quirks, but I don't know for sure...

Comment: I recently came across [this Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405794%28v=vs.85%29) which describes the line-height handling differences of almost standards mode. I discuss it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206730/html5-vs-html4-h1-tag-rendered-with-extra-space-how-to-remove/11217791#11217791) which is also relevant to your question. In particular, it is the absence of the handling of the strut which causes the difference that you see.

Comment: Just hit this issue. it is 2016 outside, but we're still dealing with the same issues :( thank you for your answer anyway!

Comment: Thanks! Just ran into this exact issue.